# rbind on a dataset inside a loop

Tags: r, loops, multiple-tables

I have loop that goes through twice. At the end of each iteration it creates **two..."new"....and "different"** sets of observations..... which i am storing in dataframes dataA and dataB. I am combining these two datasets dataA and dataB using left_join and creating one one final dataset.

```
 days = seq(from=as.Date('2011-08-01'), to=as.Date("2011-08-02"),by='days')
 for ( i in seq_along(days) )
 {
   .
   .
   dataA
   .
   .
   dataB
   .
   .
   dataC = left_join(dataA, dataB, by="ID")     

 }
```

What I want is for the dataset dataC to be updated something like rbind after each iteration. At the end of 1st iteration dataC will have 100 observations at the 2nd iteration will generate 50 new observations so this should get updated into dataC  and dataC should have 100+50 = 150 observations. No clue where to start, need help doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your loop:

```
DataD <- data.frame()
```

At the end of your loop:

```
DataD <- rbind(DataD, DataC)
```

Comment: @nicola, Romain and maRtin, this worked perfect but I am wondering about running out memory if I increase the number of iteration

Comment: You can export a csv table in each iteration, and merge them at the very end. This should reduce memory usage during the loop execution.

Comment: your suggestion might be perfect but I have to think about how to implement that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 #initialize a list before the loop
 res<-vector("list",length(days))
 #inside the loop set the i-th element of the list
 res[[i]]<-left_join(dataA, dataB, by="ID")
 #rbind all the elements after the loop
 res<-do.call(rbind,res)
```

Comment: Or use `dplyr::bind_rows` instead of `do.call(rbind)`